# Rails / Postgres: “must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function”

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm using this method:

```
  def self.lines_price_report(n)
    Income.group('date(filled_at)').having("date(filled_at) > ?", Date.today - n).sum(:lines_price)
  end
```

I'm getting this error in Heroku:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "incomes.filled_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause 
or be used in an aggregate function
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

**Executed query:**

```
SELECT SUM("incomes"."lines_price") AS sum_lines_price, date(filled_at)
AS date_filled_at FROM "incomes"
HAVING (date(filled_at) > '2012-12-04')
GROUP BY date(filled_at) ORDER BY filled_at ASC
```

**Expected result**

```
[["2012-12-04", SUM_FOR_DATE], ["2012-12-05", SUM_FOR_DATE], ...]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake was to use filled_at in order by probably in default scope.

You can fix it using unscoped to eliminate default scopes:

```
Income.unscoped
 .group('date(filled_at)')
 .having("date(filled_at) > ?", Date.today - n)
 .sum(:lines_price)
```

or

```
Income.unscoped
   .group('date(filled_at)')
   .having("date(filled_at) > ?", Date.today - n)
   .sum(:lines_price)
   .order('date(filled_at) ASC')
```

but I think that better will be to use where instead of having

```
Income.unscoped
  .where("date(filled_at) > TIMESTAMP ?", Date.today - n)
  .group('date(filled_at)')
  .sum(:lines_price)
  .order('date(filled_at) ASC')
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/af15e/12)

You have to be careful about using TIMESTAMP because 2012-12-04 will become 2012-12-04 00:00:00 so if you don't want this day in result use Date.today - (n - 1)

If you create index on filled_at column

```
 create index incomes_filled_at on incomes(filled_at);
```

migration:

```
 add_index :incomes, :filled_at
```

and you have a lot of data in this table index will be used in filtering. So query should be much faster.

So just write both and test which is faster (you have to create index on filled_at if you don't have one).

Comment: `reorder` can be used to overwrite default ordering. `unscoped` will drop all default scope, which may be undesired. Using `where` instead of `having` is a good idea.

Comment: @khustochka I agree with `reorder` instead of `unsocped` if you have more than one default scope. I changed answer.

Comment: Thank you it works. Why is where better than having ? And how do I create an index on filled_at?

Comment: @alex read whole answer. combined with index query should be faster but depend on two things.How much data is in table and how much will be filtered by date range.

Comment: @sufleR It's a big table indeed. And there will be lot of filtering.

Comment: @sufleR Thank you, is it necessary to add an index to `lines_price` too ?

Comment: @alex No. You should create indexes on columns where filtering happens often - in most cases where you use column in join (foreign key column) or if you use column in where clause and of course on primary keys and unique constraints.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is because you use `date(filled_at)` in GROUP BY but just `filled at` in ORDER. As I guess order is taken from default scope you need to overwrite it by `reorder`. I would suggest:

```
Income.sum(:lines_price).
    group('date(filled_at)').
    having("date(filled_at) > ?", Date.today - n).
    reorder("date(filled_at) ASC")
```

Comment: I agree. The ORDER BY is adding 'filled_at' (without the date bit) as an implicit SELECT, which has to appear in the GROUP BY.

Comment: It's working but is it strange that I get an array of array without using select_rows? I run that in rails console:  `Income.group('date(filled_at)').having("date(filled_at) > ?", Date.today - n).reorder("date(filled_at) ASC").sum(:lines_price).to_a` and got `[["2012-12-05", #<BigDecimal:b6dd2c8,'0.413E4',9(18)>], ...]]`.

Comment: You are right, this is how `sum` and other AR aggregations work (it actually returns a hash with keys as column grouped by, and values as sum, and `to_a` converts it to array of arrays). Thanks for correcting me, I removed my longer explanation as it was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use Group By on PostgreSQL, The select option should be required on the group by.

```
Income.select('filled_at').group('date(filled_at)').having("date(filled_at) > ?", Date.today - n).sum(:lines_price)
```